# Integral formula for a Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, greens-function

The domain I am considering is $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus a sphere centered at the origin. So it is an *unbounded* domain.

I would like to know if there exists an integral formula for representing solutions $u$ of the Poisson equation $$-\Delta u=f,$$ with *Neumann boundary conditions* on the sphere $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=g,$$ and another appropriate condition for the "boundary" at infinity, like $\|\nabla u\|=0$ at infinity.

In other words, I would like to know if there exists a similar formula to the Green's third identity for this setting.

Any reference would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Kelvin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_transform) 
$$u^{*}(x^{*})= {\frac{1}{|x^{*}|^{{n-2}}}}u\left({\frac  {R^{2}}{|x^{*}|^{2}}}x^{*}\right),\qquad x^{*}={\frac  {R^{2}}{|x|^{2}}}x.$$
reduces the problem in exterior to a problem inside the ball, because the transformed function $u^*$ satisfies
$$- \Delta u^{*}(x^{*})={\frac  {R^{{4}}}{|x^{*}|^{{n+2}}}}f\left({\frac  {R^{2}}{|x^{*}|^{2}}}x^{*}\right)$$ 
This also suggests an appropriate condition to impose at infinity: it is needed so that $u^*$ does not become singular at $0$.

The inhomogeneous exterior Neumann boundary condition becomes an inhomogeneous interior Neumann boundary condition, for a function $g^*$ that is related to $g$.

It remains to use the integral representation of solutions in a ball, based on Neumann Green's function. Luckily, the explicit form of this function [is known for the case $n=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1081097), the source being the book *Partial Differential Equations* by Emmanuele DiBenedetto.